# Internet Explorer Mobile Window.Open alternative

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, windows-phone-8

currently I'm struggling with the mobile Version of the Internet Explorer (Lumia 820 with Lumia Black Update)

I need to open a new Tab / Window and communicate between the first and second window. This works fine on Desktop using window.open(...).

It seems like the mobile IE does not support this feature of opening a new Tab...
Do you know about an alternative?